# Simulate new data based on existing data of people nested within groups in r

Tags: r, simulation, statsmodels

I have a dataset of people nested within groups (6 people per group). People within each group are assigned either a condition A or B and the proportions within each group change. Each person in the group provides ratings to some stimuli. I am hoping to generate a simulation that increases this dataset using this nested structure. How would you recommend doing that?

here is a simulated data in r:

```
# Generate the groups
num_groups <- 5  # Number of groups
group_size <- 6  # Size of each group

# Assign people to groups
people <- rep(1:num_groups, each = group_size)

# Assign conditions to people within each group
conditions <- rep(c("A", "B"), times = num_groups * group_size / 2) 

# Generate random ratings
ratings <- runif(num_groups * group_size, min = 1, max = 10)

# Create the dataset
dataset <- data.frame(Person = people, Condition = conditions, Rating = ratings)
```